# Stream dynamic zip files with resume support

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

Suppose, I have a list of MP3 files on my server. And I want a user to download multiple files (which he wants through any means). For, this what i want is to create the zip file dynamically and while saving it into the Output Stream using the **dotnetzip** or **ioniczip** libraries.

Well, that's not the perfect solution if the zip file got heavy in size. As, in that scenario the server doesn't support resumable downloads. So, to overcome this approach, I need to handle the zip file structure internally and provide the **resume** support.

So, is there any library (open source) which i can use to provide **resumable dyanamic zip** files stream directly to the **Output Stream**. Or, if possible I will be happy if someone let me know the structure of zip file specially the **header content** + **data content**.

Comment: This site is for asking about specific problems.  You need to narrow the topic down and provide examples of your research and attempts so far.

Comment: we are not here to write solution for you. What have you done so far and maybe we can help from there.

Comment: Well, I looked into a library Ionic.Zip which can stream dynamic zip files in which files get added at runtime. But, it doesn't support resume downloads. And, thats what i was looking for. I hope that could narrow down a little bit on my research.

Answer (score 0):

Once a download has started, you should not alter the ZIP file anymore. Because then a resume will just result in a broken ZIP file. So make sure your dynamically created ZIP file stays available!

The issue of providing resume-functionality was solved [in this article for .NET 1.1](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/22533), and it is still valid and functional.

Comment: Well, that's the trick Alexander, that i made zip files dynamically in asp.net.

Comment: Yes, save the ZIP file and serve it to the client. Done. Or make sure you recreate it the very same way on each and every request. Which will kill your server.

Comment: No, that solution is not feasible for me.

Comment: Which one, saving a file of recreating it every time?

Comment: Well saving the zip file before transmitting it means increase the load on the server PLUS hold the user request until the zip finishes. I want instant zip (on the fly) and then flush the response in chunks as it writes into the output stream (zip stream)

Comment: Now I understood completely what you mean. 
If my memory of the ZIP-file architecture serves me right, you cannot do that. Also, how would act when a resume request comes for the same file?

Comment: What is so wrong in the zip file architecture? I believe you might be thinking of the CRC32 of the files being added, Correct?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the ZIP architecture, it's your wish of not saving them but being able to create them on the fly, in memory, again and again, with resume support. With each teeny tiny request, your server will have to recreate the file. If a customer uses a download manager and makes 10 concurrent request, THEN you'll have server load.

Comment: But, i believe if i created the zip on fly smart enough that i don't need to re-create whole file again then the server would be happy too. Assume, a download manager makes 10 concurrent connection then in that case, i stream the zip content exactly which is being requested. Its just like dynamically streaming a content with resume support. Hope it makes a little sense.

Comment: Yes I understood your idea, and that's when I wrote that I do not believe ZIP architecture lets you do that. I COULD be wrong, though. You'd have to do your own ZIP implementation from the beginning. And then, I'd risk a bet to say server load would be higher with your approach. Sorry.

Comment: But, let me ask you one question that, whether it requires the CRC32 of the file which is getting zipped prior to stream the zip content? As this is where i stuck actually, and if its not necessary then i am sure that it can done with ease without any server load.